# Do an action when someone edit one page on Mediawiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm trying to perform an action when someone edit a page on my Mediawiki. The action is exec a .sh script (for example with this code: exec('sh /path/file.sh');). I analized the EditPages.php and I didn't find where I could add this command.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding [hooks](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks) to your Mediawiki installation. In your case you register to the [PageContentSaveComplete](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/PageContentSaveComplete) event.